# TabbedPage icons not shown when set position to bottom

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, tabbedpage

I am a beginner in Xamarin and trying to use TabbedPage for my application. When I used TabbedPage and set the icons, it works fine.

[image]

Then I set the TabbedPage position to bottom using below link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/tabbedpage-toolbar-placement-color

However, when I run the application, the TabbedPage icons are not visible and even the width is too long for one Tab

[image]

Below is my XAML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="//xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
        xmlns:x="//schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:App5.Views"
        x:Class="App5.Views.MainPage"
        BarBackgroundColor="LightYellow"
        BarTextColor="Black"
        xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
        android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
        android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Black"
        android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Red">
<TabbedPage.Children>
    <NavigationPage Title="Tab1" Icon="Tab1.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ItemsPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Tab2" Icon="Tab2.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:AboutPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Tab3" Icon="Tab3.png">
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:AboutPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
    <NavigationPage Title="Tab4" Icon="Tab4.png">
    <x:Arguments>
        <views:AboutPage />
    </x:Arguments>
</NavigationPage>
</TabbedPage.Children>
```

Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there may be an issue with the space between the tab when it is selected. You need to disable the zooming effect when the tab is selected.

Create the custom tab reader to disable the zooming effect for Android.

**BottomTabbedPageRenderer.cs**

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(BottomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace Droid.Renderer

{
    public class BottomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
    public BottomTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
    {
        base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);
        try
        {
            var children = GetAllChildViews(ViewGroup);

            if (children.SingleOrDefault(x => x is BottomNavigationView) is BottomNavigationView bottomNav)
            {

                try
                {
                    if (!(bottomNav.GetChildAt(0) is BottomNavigationMenuView menuView))
                    {
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Unable to find BottomNavigationMenuView");
                        return;
                    }


                    var shiftMode = menuView.Class.GetDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");

                    shiftMode.Accessible = true;
                    shiftMode.SetBoolean(menuView, false);
                    shiftMode.Accessible = false;
                    shiftMode.Dispose();


                    for (int i = 0; i < menuView.ChildCount; i++)
                    {
                        if (!(menuView.GetChildAt(i) is BottomNavigationItemView item))
                            continue;

                        item.SetShiftingMode(false);
                        item.SetChecked(item.ItemData.IsChecked);

                    }

                    menuView.UpdateMenuView();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to set shift mode: {ex}");
                }

            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error setting ShiftMode: {e}");
        }
    }

    private List<View> GetAllChildViews(View view)
    {
        if (!(view is ViewGroup group))
        {
            return new List<View> { view };
        }

        var result = new List<View>();

        for (int i = 0; i < group.ChildCount; i++)
        {
            var child = group.GetChildAt(i);

            var childList = new List<View> { child };
            childList.AddRange(GetAllChildViews(child));

            result.AddRange(childList);
        }

        return result.Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
}
```

**MyTabPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TabbedPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    BarBackgroundColor="LightYellow"
    BarTextColor="Black"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Demo"
    xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
    android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
    x:Class="Demo.MyTabPage">
    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage
            Title="Tab1"
            Icon="dashboard_selected.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:MainPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage
            Title="Tab2"
            Icon="dashboard.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:MainPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage
            Title="Tab3"
            Icon="error_alert.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:MainPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
        <NavigationPage
            Title="Tab4"
            Icon="menu.png">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:MainPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children>
</TabbedPage>
```

I put all the images resources in the drawable folder with xhdpi,mdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi with the same name and In my case, it is working fine.

[image: Demo]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have implemented the same and the width was properly set, but do you have any idea about icons as well, because they are still not visible

Comment: Remove `android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Black" android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Red">` and try

Comment: @User5590, I have used your XAML code and tried. It is working. I have removed `android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="Black" android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="Red">` and is working fine. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me check from my side and will let you know the result

Comment: I tried that but still the same result Can you please share your demo solution as zip?

Comment: Where have you kept the image resources for android?

Comment: I just copied the provided icons in ios project (tab_feed, tab_about) to android Drawable folder and guess what. I was able to see icons at bottom as well.

Comment: I just found that, the icon which I was using was of resolution 38x27, however it the existing icons are of 32x30. Is there any specific resolution required for icons?

Comment: No, it will work. Even I have the different size of the icons. You need to put all the icons in the Android and iOS resources. If you still have an issue, just send me a code I will make it correct and send you back.

Comment: ohk, in my case I didn;t copy it to ios project. I just copied it to Drawable folder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187468/discussion-between-jaymin-and-user5590).

Answer (score 1):

As @User5590 and @Jaymin mentioned in Jaymin's answer comments, it is related to tabbar icon's resolutions (I didn't need to implement custom renderer). Here's what I did:

1. Go to this [Online Android Asset Studio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-actionbar.html) and in the *Source* section choose *Image* and upload your desired tabbar icon:

[image]

2. Choose your tab icon's name from the left panel:

[image]

And download the zip file by clicking the blue icon:

[image]

3. Now that we have our tab icon for all resolutions in the zip file, place them in corespondent folder in your Android project. For example move *tab_icon.png* in drawable-xxxhdpi folder of zip file to same folder in Android project.

Note: make sure you set the `Title` and `Icon` properties of every page, for example in first page's XAML:

`Icon="tab_icon.png"`

And here's the final result:

[image]